# Internal Notebook Display not detected with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics, xorg, display

the internal display of my notebook is not detected with Ubuntu 20.4. The two external monitor
works fine. However, the internal display does not work at all.

I have a Tuxedo XP1610 with a NVIDIA graphics card. Following is some information about
the system. If you need more information to analyze the problem, please tell me.
How can i very / test why the internal display of the notebook is not detected / working.

Thanks in advance.

```
~ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
```

```
~ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1011712  0
nvidia_drm             49152  11
nvidia_modeset       1183744  24 nvidia_drm
nvidia              19742720  1109 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   491520  14 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
```

```
~ cat  /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "EE"
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    17.838] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    17.840] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    17.840] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    17.841] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    17.848] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
```